# onerror="this.style.display='none'" doesnt work in Firefox

Tags: html, css, angular

`onerror="this.style.display='none'"` works fine in Chrome but in Firefox the image is hidden but when you look in inspect element it has a display none on it. which isn't what I want I just need the image to be hidden if the image is broken. 
Images are being pulled in via cms system.

Comment: Works fine when I try it: https://jsfiddle.net/981yj4zt/

Comment: cheers for the reply....however when i look at your jsfiddle the broken image is still there. :(

Comment: Check the source more closely. There are two images, one with your technique, one without, to demonstrate that it works. You should only see the one with the red border - the one with the green is hidden correctly in Firefox and Chrome both.

Comment: @matt1993 the image which is visible is without `onerror` event..try to inspect....

Comment: cheers again... got it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to check if `onerror` event is executing or not you can test in script e.g.

```
onerror="this.style.display='none';alert('test');"`
```

I feel its not firefox issue as it works for me and others.

Comment: cheers for the reply... i did the Alert(test) and thats fine the pop up appeared .